# How to use guacamole in my own django project

Tags: django, guacamole

Recently, I was writing a Django project with guacamole. How can I insert the guacamole windows to my Django page?

I tried to use iframe( the IP of django is **localhost:8000** and IP of guacamole is **localhost:8080** , but then user will have to input the username and password of guacamole even he has logined the Django page.

Of couse the Django page can get the username and password of guacamole with ajax request, but it seems that we can't manipulate the element of inner iframe whose IP is different from the outer webpage.

I use urllib2 (from Django web server) to send a request to guacamole( **localhost:8080/guacamole/api/tokens** with username and password, only get a token, I don't know how to use it nor whether it will work.

I tried to send the request by the web browser, but get an error **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.142:8080/guacamole/api/tokens. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.**

I don't want user to input the username and password which is terrible. How can I fix it? Thank you for your watching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to use iframe ...

I must caution against using an `iframe` for this. It seems invitingly simple, but beyond the problems you've already encountered, managing browser keyboard focus with respect to an `iframe` is difficult. Your users will be confused when typing within Guacamole does not work. The best way to embed Guacamole in a different application is to leverage Guacamole's JavaScript and Java APIs: [guacamole-common](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-common/) and [guacamole-common-js](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/) respectively (more on this below).

> I use urllib2 (from Django web server) to send a request to guacamole( localhost:8080/guacamole/api/tokens with username and password, only get a token, I don't know how to use it nor whether it will work.

You do not need to hack your way around the Guacamole web application's authentication system, etc. to embed Guacamole within something else - the Guacamole project provides a set of APIs for this purpose. If you wish to use Guacamole within another project, the ideal way to do this is to use its JavaScript API, while leveraging the Java API strictly for the tunnel portion of the backend: http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html

Writing your application in this way will allow you to dictate what authentication mechanism, if any, will apply for the tunnels used by the Guacamole JavaScript client embedded in your application, as well as exactly how the configuration information for each connection is derived or retrieved, and since you would be using the Guacamole JavaScript client directly, there would be no `iframe`.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This error is due to a violation of the browser's [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Since you are encountering this while mixing "localhost" and a private IP (192.168.1.142), it looks like this is mainly due to how you are testing the application, and I'm not sure whether you would be encountering this problem as your project matures. If this problem continues, there are two primary ways of dealing with cross-origin problems:

1. Proxy Guacamole using Apache or Nginx such that it is effectively served from the same domain as the rest of your application.
2. Ensure you are setting `crossDomain` to `true` when creating your [Guacamole.HTTPTunnel](http://guac-dev.org/doc/guacamole-common-js/symbols/Guacamole.HTTPTunnel.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. The java API and JavaScript API indeed provide a log of function to use. Because I can't wrote Java, so now I cooperate with a Colleague who can wrote java. I think we can solve this problem together.

Comment: @ramwin Were you able to use guacamole in your project? If so, please share the code snippet, where you connect to different remote computers from your application. Thank you

Comment: [Here](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-common.html) is the official documentation. Because the code is owned by my company, and I had left this company, it's inconvenient for me to reveal the code. I think the documentation is clear enough for developer. Try to follow it, if you come up with any question, feel happy to ask me.